# apt-cyg install fails, /usr/bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, tar

When I try to run apt-cyg to install some Cygwin package, I get the following:

```
$ apt-cyg install xterm
grep: /etc/setup/installed.db: No such file or directory
Installing xterm
xterm-327-1.tar.xz: OK
/usr/bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive
/usr/bin/tar: Skipping to next header
/usr/bin/tar: 60 garbage bytes ignored at end of archive
/usr/bin/tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
Unpacking...
/usr/bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive
/usr/bin/tar: Skipping to next header
/usr/bin/tar: 60 garbage bytes ignored at end of archive
/usr/bin/tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
/usr/bin/mv: cannot stat `/etc/setup/installed.db': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/mv: cannot stat `/tmp/awk.24556': No such file or directory
Package xterm requires the following packages, installing:
bash cygwin libICE6 libX11_6 libXaw7 libXft2 libXinerama1 libXmu6 libXpm4 libXt6 libfontconfig1 libncursesw10 luit xorg-x11-fonts-dpi75 xorg-x11-fonts-misc
grep: /etc/setup/installed.db: No such file or directory
grep: /etc/setup/installed.db: No such file or directory
Installing bash
bash-4.4.12-3.tar.xz: OK
/usr/bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive
/usr/bin/tar: Skipping to next header
/usr/bin/tar: 340 garbage bytes ignored at end of archive
/usr/bin/tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
Unpacking...
/usr/bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive
/usr/bin/tar: Skipping to next header
/usr/bin/tar: 340 garbage bytes ignored at end of archive
/usr/bin/tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
/usr/bin/mv: cannot stat `/etc/setup/installed.db': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/mv: cannot stat `/tmp/awk.7756': No such file or directory
Package bash requires the following packages, installing:
coreutils cygwin libiconv2 libintl8 libreadline7
grep: /etc/setup/installed.db: No such file or directory
grep: /etc/setup/installed.db: No such file or directory
```

It performs this in a loop, continuously returning back to the original package, and then iterating through its dependencies.

I am using Cygwin on Windows 10. I have attempted:

- Reinstalling Cygwin and apt-cyg (hoping, mostly, that the root of this was some sort of faulty tar install or bad settings file a reinstall would restore to default)
- Running Cygwin in an cmd shell that is "run as administrator"
- Modifying my PATH variable to have /cygwin/bin at the top, heirarchically
- Waiting patiently for the Sun to eventually expand and swallow the Earth

Any suggestions that can help me forward would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: you could also try asking on the cygwin mailing list..  Also are you interested in trying to install the package the normal way through the GUI which existed before the apt-cyg(which seems to be very new)?  or a command line way that uses the cygwin installation(might also predate apt-cyg). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260014/how-do-i-install-cygwin-components-from-the-command-line

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the GUI." There is a setup file you traditionally rerun to install new packages, but it takes ages. There is no native package manager in cygwin.

Comment: As you are missing `/etc/setup/installed.db` or you have a damaged installation or your apt-cyg is looking in the wrong directory. Not clear what you mean with setup takes ages.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cygwin` installation is corrupt or your `apt-cyg` thinks so,
as the database of installed package  `/etc/setup/installed.db` is missing.

```
Package xterm requires the following packages, installing:
bash cygwin libICE6 libX11_6 libXaw7 libXft2 libXinerama1 libXmu6 libXpm4 libXt6 libfontconfig1 libncursesw10 luit xorg-x11-fonts-dpi75 xorg-x11-fonts-misc
grep: /etc/setup/installed.db: No such file or directory
```

`apt-cyg` can not install `bash cygwin` as they are prerequisite for `apt-cyg` to work correctly.
Use setup and reinstall needed packages.